# Sharing Violation on path in Adcolony

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, adcolony

I have a completed game working properly in Android and is published on Play store already. Now I wanted to submit it on iTunes. As soon as I started building the same project for iOS, I got this strange Error -

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path /Users/abhi/Projects/Unity/XCode Proj/Hammer Inc/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:167)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string)
System.IO.File.OpenText (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:368)
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:560)
AdColonyPostProcessBuild.updateXcodeProject (System.String pbxProjectFilePath, System.String thirdPartyFrameworkDirectoryPath, .Framework[] frameworksToAdd) (at Assets/Editor/AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs:356)
AdColonyPostProcessBuild.OnPostProcessBuild (BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at Assets/Editor/AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs:340)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I got this error, after I was having some trouble with GPG Plugin and as mentioned [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/61), I deleted the files and folders related to Google Play gaming, since I planned to use Game Center in iOS.

I am currently using Native-X, Adcolony, Revmob in the same project (I know that's too much, but that was due to an experiment on choosing proper network). I am not sure which of the plugin is causing conflicts.

I tried removing the AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs file, but it gave the following error -

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (.TKey
key) (at
/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/
corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXResolver.ResolveName (System.String guid) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:49)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXResolver.ResolveName (System.String guid) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:53)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.GUIDComment (System.String guid,
System.Text.StringBuilder builder) (at Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX
Editor/PBXParser.cs:218)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.SerializeString (System.String
aString, System.Text.StringBuilder builder, Boolean useQuotes, Boolean
readable) (at Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:546)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.SerializeDictionary
(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 dictionary,
System.Text.StringBuilder builder, Boolean readable, Int32 indent) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:481)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.SerializeValue (System.Object value,
System.Text.StringBuilder builder, Boolean readable, Int32 indent) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:439)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.SerializeDictionary
(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 dictionary,
System.Text.StringBuilder builder, Boolean readable, Int32 indent) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:489)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.SerializeValue (System.Object value,
System.Text.StringBuilder builder, Boolean readable, Int32 indent) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:439)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXParser.Encode
(UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXDictionary pbxData, Boolean readable) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/PBX Editor/PBXParser.cs:177)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.XCProject.CreateNewProject
(UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.PBXDictionary result, System.String path) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/XCProject.cs:620)
UnityEditor.XCodeEditor.XCProject.Save () (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/XCProject.cs:645) XCodePostProcess.OnPostProcessBuild
(BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at
Assets/Editor/iOS/XCodePostProcess.cs:35) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Did anyone faced this issue before and found any solution? I don't want to delete every SDK from the project and start building it again.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have a couple of issues. That sounds like a bummer. But, I would definitely like to help.

### What's Happening:

Regarding the first error that you've provided it looks like it's having an issue reading the pbxproj file that Unity creates for the iOS build process.

Typically, when building for iOS, Unity will create a .pbxproj file in conjunction with the rest of the XCode items and then place that in the target build directory you specify. After that it triggers any post process build logic that has been hooked in by the developer.

AdColony's AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs file is generally intended to be run last out of the post process build logic, because we rely on parsing the .pbxproj file itself, and then adding the information in line by line. The reason we prefer to do this last is because there exist current solutions to this problem that don't necessarily facilitate all the configurations we need, but other developers use it.

The first error looks like it's an access violation issue with the AdColonyPostProcessBuild not being able to access the .pbxproj file, so it can read in all of the lines. Because of this it's throwing an IOException seen here:

IOException: Sharing violation on path /Users/abhi/Projects/Unity/XCode Proj/Hammer Inc/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

and

System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:560)
AdColonyPostProcessBuild.updateXcodeProject (System.String pbxProjectFilePath, System.String thirdPartyFrameworkDirectoryPath, .Framework[] frameworksToAdd) (at Assets/Editor/AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs:356)

This brings me to my next point.

The second error that you've listed is something that arises out of an alternative post process build logic called "XCode Editor For Unity".

You can find it here:

https://github.com/dcariola/XCodeEditor-for-Unity

This solution is a C# implementation of a solution known as mod_pbxproj, and other developers have opted for this solution. However, when using it in conjunction with AdColony it will typically break if the XCode Editor For Unity is performed after the AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs is run.

This is because some of the information used for the XCode Editor For Unity parsing has been duplicated and is being read in twice, when AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs is run.

AdColony has configured our post process logic to run last, relying on the ability to parse the information after the XCode Editor For Unity has been run.

### The Suggested Solution

The information you've provided has been very helpful, but it's hard to say for certain why these may be arising.

What will facilitate this process is if you could list any other plug-ins you're using that have a post process build applied for iOS builds AND if you can also provide any indications of their priority or order of occurrence on build.

Following that, the line numbers I see in your error output appear a bit inconsistent with the current version of the AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs file in our current available package.

I would first suggest going to this link, downloading the current package, and re-importing the AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs
https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Unity-SDK

If that doesn't resolve the issue, I would then open up the AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs file and change its priority to be lower, preferably to be the last post process build item to run. You can do this by changing the number '200' on line 302, to a great number, like '1000'.

If this doesn't resolve your problem I will need to know more about your environment configuration like other plug-ins you are using, and deviations you've made from the default AdColonyPostProcessBuild.cs file.

Regards!

AdColony Support

Comment: Thanks for the help. This helped in understanding the issue. I'll try the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem arose for me because I was using the Facebook SDK with Adcolony's SDK. The Facebook code leaves a streamReader open which produces the error when the Adcolony script is run. Change lines in Assets\Facebook\Editor\iOS\third_party\XCodeEditor-for-Unity\XCProject.cs

from (lines 76-77):

```
projectFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(this.filePath, "project.pbxproj"));
string contents = projectFileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

to:

```
projectFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(this.filePath, "project.pbxproj"));
StreamReader sr = projectFileInfo.OpenText();
string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

(credit to the answer here: ["IOException: Sharing violation on path" on building a Unity project on Mac OS X with Facebook Unity SDK 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836364/ioexception-sharing-violation-on-path-on-building-a-unity-project-on-mac-os-x))